# Java KeyListener Class

Tags: java, user-interface, keylistener, pacman

I have a `Keylistener` class for a game I am making an something has bpne wrong with it. I can't seem to get the pacman move with the key clicks. It seems as if the `Keylistener` method isn't ever being called. I'm relatively new to Java and GUI interfaces so forgive me if my coding is a bit rusty.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PacRunner implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    private static Grid gr;
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
    gr = new Grid();
    gr.addGhost(new Location(4,11));
    gr.movePac(new Location(6,11));
    gr.show();
    }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) gr.move(Location.UP);          
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) gr.move(Location.DOWN);
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) gr.move(Location.LEFT);
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) gr.move(Location.RIGHT);
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  The problem with `KeyListener` is usually that either a) The component does not have focus or.. b)  The component is not focusable, -- For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW - Is this using AWT or Swing based components?

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably forgetting is in your main method is to add this line of code:

```
component.addKeyListener(keyListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not registered your KeyListener. The KeyListener has to be added.

The java.awt.Component class contains the method [addKeyListener(KeyListener l)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29)

You will have to identify which `java.awt.Component` you wish to intercept the event. Once you have identified that Component, you will call this method using, `PacRunner` as the `KeyListener` argument :

```
component.addKeyListener(myPacRunner);
```

or, if that method is called from within the PacRunner instance :

```
component.addKeyListener(this);
```

In order to implement this pattern in your provided code, assuming that the class `Grid` extends `Component`, you would first instantiate your PacRunner, then add that PacRunner instance as a `KeyListener` to the `Grid`

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    PacRunner myPacRunner = new PacRunner(); // An Empty constructor inherited from Object
    gr = new Grid();
    gr.addKeyListener(myPacRunner);
    ...
}
```

For a more complete treatment of the topic. See [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) in the Java Tutorials.

Comment: Ok, I can't add that to the static void main. Where would I add that in the program to make it work correctly?

Comment: Does Grid extend component ? If not, please provide some information regarding your GUI.

Comment: I've edited the example to illustrate one possible method for using an Instance of PacRunner as a KeyListener within the static main method